# Correct use of the 'spawnactor' command?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So I'm playing a game of Crusader Kings 2 at the moment and am trying to recreate the 'Vikings' TV show as much as possible. It's not exactly historically accurate, so I'm using the console commands a lot.

Anyway, I can use pretty much every console command effectively apart from one:

```
spawnactor
```

From this documentation:

```
https://commands.gg/ck2/spawnactor
https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Provinces
```

It seems like the syntax I need to spawn a character (we'll call him Harald Finehair) is:

```
spawnactor [actor name] [province id] [animation] [title id]
```

So I've tried:

```
spawnactor 'Harald Finehair' Uppland
spawnactor 'Harald Finehair' c_uppland
spawnactor 'Harald Finehair' 290
```

However, nothing I try works. I don't get any error messages telling me the syntax is wrong or that the command is not allowed. It almost seems like it has worked, but nothing appears to happen as a result.

The last two parameters are apparently optional, so:

```
animation
title_id
```

appear to be unnecessary.

All I really need to know is, how in this game do I spawn a new character? New characters appear with certain events, so spawning a new one must be possible via command console. I've never managed to get it working though.

Can anyone explain the correct use of this command, or tell me how to do what I am seeking to do?